# Turning a mysql column into a php array and echoing it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having some problem when I try to select a column from my table in MySQL and turn it into a PHP array. When I echo my result (the PHP array), it doesn't return me anything.

Here is my code:

```
$result_while = mysql_query("SELECT id` 
      FROM afunda_eleva");

$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_while)) {
  $array[] = $result_while['id'];
}

for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    echo "$array[$i]"; //Possibly error happening here!!
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the first backtick around 'id' in your SQL. It's probably returning an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if you wish to work with column names in your array you need to replace `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Then you need to access the row, not the result, inside your `while` loop:

```
$array[] = $row['id'];
```

Comment: Hmm, really! It worked now! I've been through this for a reasonable time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Gustavo `mysql_query` is deprecated in the newer PHP version, it is unsafe but does the job.
Instead I rather give you an answer with my favorite way of query databases
**PDO** it is secure and it is object-oriented.

first we need to set it up

```
// instance of pdo
$config['db'] = array
(
    'host' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => ''
);
$database = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . 
';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'],
$config['db']['username'],
$config['db']['password']);
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

//query with a new database object
$queryObject = $database->prepare("SELECT id 
FROM afunda_eleva");
//execute sql
$queryObject ->execute();
// store the results in array
$results = $queryObject->fetchAll();
//print_r results to test 
print_r($results);
//after analysing the array and how its structured define
for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    echo $results[$i] 
}
```

try that code with your database credentials on the instance, if you want to include this in a seperate db file that gets included before calling pdo make sure you call `global $database;` to call upon its instance

here is a good pdo tutorials playlist, good luck

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQjKkNiByCk

Comment: +1 very good example. I am not advocating sticking to `mysql_*` but GustavoxD had to understand his mistake in the context of his own code.

Comment: @Sébastien sorry both of you have latin names i didnt know who asked it, i did not mean to call upon you. sorry

Answer (score 1):

1- To get the result you have to put `$row` instead `$result_while['id]`

2-In order to print an array you have to use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

```
$result_while = mysql_query("SELECT id` 
      FROM afunda_eleva");

$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_while)) {
  $array[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '<pre>';
```

Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

**Side Note:** [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) a useful link

Comment: As Sébastien suggested, i thought the problem was up to the " $array[] = $result_while['id'];". But thanks for the mysqli tips though! I'm beginning my studies.